# API Connect designer issue

Tags: ibm-cloud, rollback, apiconnect

I am trying to learn IBM API Connect and installed the toolkit following this
[tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/apiconnect/getting-started/).

For starting API Designer the command is:

```
apic edit
Express server listening on http://127.0.0.1:9000
```

But http://127.0.0.1:9000 doesnt work in browser. I get...

> This site can’t be reached
>   127.0.0.1 took too long to respond.

I tried by changing port. It still doesn't work. 
Apiconnect version is v5.0.6.0 (apiconnect v2.5.8)

Comment: Do you have any proxy set in your browser? Try to run the following command `curl http://127.0.0.1:9000` in a terminal and see if works. You can try http://localhost:9000 as well.

Comment: No proxy is set. I have tried them. Both did not work.

Comment: Can you try hitting it at http://0.0.0.0:9000/login.html?

Comment: I have tried Uninstalling and installing again. It is not working.  I'm doing this in Windows 10

Comment: Did you make sure that your firewall is letting requests flow through?

Comment: Assuming port 9000 is not in use, you might want to try other browser, e.g. Chrome.

Comment: @JohnSeen: Are you still having issues here?